# crashlytics can't run/reference/import

Tags: java, android, crashlytics

I have been trying to install crashlytics for the passed 6 hours with no succes.

The first time it started downloading some libraries but something went wrong and I had to delete them all again. I'm talking about the ones that it places in the lib folder it creates (not sure of the exact name of that folder).

After that it simply refuses to redownload them and just sits there on the "build and launch the app" window so it can "verify" its configuration.

So here's the issue, because it doesn't download the stupid libraries i can't import them in any of my classes or use them.

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

gives errors ofcourse because it can't resolve "Fabric" or "Crashlytics". Why the people at crashlytics don't give you the simple option to download the jar file(s) yourself is beyond me...

In any case, here's what I've tried:

- uninstalling the eclipse plugin
- searching for EVERY reference to fabric and crashlytics and deleting them if relevant
- deleting all contents and whatnot
- deleting eclipse's artifacts.xml file
- Since it's a git project I even deleted all the project files, created a new git folder and pulled them again there.
- manually attempt to put some of the jars from the plugin folder in my libs folder and adding them to my build path

but nothing works... help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the steps to integrate Crashlytics to application.

If it is first time then fabric will support you in doing the setup.

1. https://fabric.io/onboard given option to select SDK.
2. Select SDK and started integrating.
3. Successfully able to add plugin.
4. After SDK restarts, clicked on the Fabric toolbar button to start using Fabric!
5. Logged in -> Selected project -> selected kit to install.
6. Follow all the steps initiated by tools.

   - change of android-manifest file.
   - add code in the java class.
   - add shown code to kits.properties (Eg: com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.2)
7. Final step will show you the done. (If you haven't done the three steps properly in step 6 then you can't be proceed further).

Comment: so, apparently after I deleted all the files the first time it somehow managed to put com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.2 after a comment sign.
Meaning the plugin ignored the downloading part and i could therefore not download the damn thing.
Thanks to you good sir/madam I realized I should check the kits file and  sure enough the issue was there.

What frustration can do to you...